# Why my code gives error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: "?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

Why is my program giving me error indicating that that column does not exist in my `Sqlite3` `Tasks`-table? Here is my code:

```
class Db:

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        create_Tasks_table = '''CREATE TABLE Tasks (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    notes TEXT,
                    deadline TEXT, 
                    state INTEGER);'''
        self.cursor.execute(create_Tasks_table)
        self.conn.commit()


    def add_task(self, title, notes, deadline):
        state = 0
        add_to_Tasks_table = """INSERT INTO Tasks (title, notes, deadline, state) values (?, ?, ?, ?), (title, notes, deadline, state)"""
        self.cursor.execute(add_to_Tasks_table)
        self.conn.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = Db()
    db.create_table()
    db.add_task("title1", "Note1", "2021-10-30 18:00:00")
```

I checked with `DB Browser for SQlite` that table is created correctly and column name is correct, as indicated on this picture:
[image]

EDIT: Here is full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project\mytest.py", line 91, in <module>
    db.add_task("title1", "Note1", "2021-10-30 18:00:00")
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project\mytest.py", line 36, in add_task
    self.cursor.execute(add_to_Tasks_table)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: title
```

Comment: It's not necessarily the problem but I don't think you want `conn` and `cursor` to be class attributes. Better to define an `__init__()` method and make them instance attributes instead.

Comment: @forpas Thanks. That stupid typo from my part. Recreating table does not fix th e error in question though.

Comment: Post full error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you included the tuple that contains the parameters that you pass inside the sql statement.
It should be placed as the 2nd argument of `cursor.execute()`:

```
def add_task(self, title, notes, deadline):
    state = 0
    add_to_Tasks_table = "INSERT INTO Tasks (title, notes, deadline, state) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    self.cursor.execute(add_to_Tasks_table, (title, notes, deadline, state))
    self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems way more clear than the original guide I took the template out of.